# Cannot get Material UI radio buttons to work with Formik

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik

I am trying to use Material UI radio buttons with Formik, and they are not clicking properly.  I've reduced the problem to the following example: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-currying-s5vn0

If anyone knows what I might be doing wrong, or if there is a bug in either system, then please let me know.  When clicking on the buttons in the above example, they do not stay clicked.  I have a more complex react functional component that uses other library components, so I cannot include it here.  It is behaving a little differently: the buttons stay clicked even after clicking a different button.  It may or may not be the same issue.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to be rendering the radio buttons inside of the `FormikRadioGroup` component you are rendering as a Formik Field.  That way you can actually pass the props being managed by Formik down to the components to be used, as well as allow the `RadioGroup` component to make sure only one button is clicked at a time.  I added an `options` prop to provide a way to pass an array of radio options and removed all of the elements you were rendering outside of that component:

```
const FormikRadioGroup = ({
  field,
  form: { touched, errors },
  name,
  options,
  ...props
}) => {

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <RadioGroup {...field} {...props} name={name}>
        {options.map(option => (
          <FormControlLabel value={option} control={<Radio />} label={option} />
        ))}
      </RadioGroup>

      {touched[fieldName] && errors[fieldName] && (
        <React.Fragment>{errors[fieldName]}</React.Fragment>
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

Fork [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-williamson-pd64p?file=/src/FormikRadioGroup.js).

**EDIT:** Updated the sandbox with an alternate example using a render function as a child within the Field component.

Comment: Thanks! that fixed the problem I described.  Unfortunately, it still have a problem getting the radio buttons to work on my component with more dependencies that I cannot post here.  I have tried your approach there too, to no success.  I will investigate more, and maybe create a new question, if I can replicate it in codesandbox.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { FormControlLabel, Radio, LinearProgress } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Formik, Field } from 'formik';
import { RadioGroup } from 'formik-material-ui';

<Formik {...otherProps}>
  {({ isSubmitting }) => (
    <Field component={RadioGroup} name="activity">
      <FormControlLabel
        value="painting"
        control={<Radio disabled={isSubmitting} />}
        label="Painting"
        disabled={isSubmitting}
      />
      <FormControlLabel
        value="drawing"
        control={<Radio disabled={isSubmitting} />}
        label="Drawing"
        disabled={isSubmitting}
      />
      <FormControlLabel
        value="none"
        control={<Radio disabled={isSubmitting} />}
        label="None"
        disabled
      />
    </Field>
  )}
</Formik>;
```

Now this is documented! Using `RadioGroup` from `formik-material-ui`.

https://stackworx.github.io/formik-material-ui/docs/api/material-ui/

Comment: please explain your answer