# Cannot get Material UI radio buttons to work with Formik Part Two

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik

Previously, I asked for help with getting radio buttons to work with Material UI and Formik here: [Cannot get Material UI radio buttons to work with Formik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58456473/cannot-get-material-ui-radio-buttons-to-work-with-formik).  Luckily, I got a fix for it, but unfortunately it did not work for our application.  Therefore, I have developed a code sandbox that more closely matches our environment, with the solution that was given in the previous question.  Can anyone give advice on how to get it to work?  For more details, we wrap Material UI, in this case the Radio.js class.  This allows us to leverage it in different projects/repos.  Here is the code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-colden-0oo63.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some help, I found this answer works.  https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-tdd-784y8

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean radio button  did not  go to checked state? 
You did not work and set the Checked Prop.
You have to use state hooks and onChange event.

See example: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-firefly-lb45t

Comment: This example does not allow selecting of different radio buttons.  Did you forget to save your work?  It doesn't seem much different from what I posted.

Comment: As you can see the init values are displayed now.

Comment: In your example, you cannot change the radio button selection.  I would like the initial values to be all unchecked.

Comment: I updated answer. You have to use state hooks and onChange event.